# How can i make changes to machine generated code

Tags: java, netbeans, checkbox

perhaps its a stupid question but I have created an interface by using the Design mode in Netbeans but now i need to make some basic changes to it, specifically i have created a part of the interface which works, in design mode but now i need to create some checkboxes array therefore i need to create them manually the issue is how can i connect these two? I mean how can i add the manually created code to the rest of the code? The automatic code wont allow me to make changes and add code to the variable declarations.I have to add codes to the following part for example

```
      // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextArea descrizione;
private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField eta;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox femmina;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField malattia;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox maschio;
 // End of variables declaration
```

Comment: My suggestion is to create your Swing user interface by hand as it's much easier to manipulate and improve than a code-generated GUI.

Comment: Well i learnt it the hard way :) I'll post the solution if i find any though. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could just open the file in another text editor, like windows notepad or whatever...

But, messing with the code, you can end up making it unreadable by the designer.

Most of the time you can do this kind of thing by selecting the component and opening the properties explorer (that box on the right side of the screen) then search for some "code" option. I know you can find there some options to insert personalized code in the component creation process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. exactly the issue is that i need both the machine generated code for the part of the interface which works and then add my own manual code which i can generate with the design mode but i cant make them work together because if make changes to the machine code it messes up the part which was working earlier. Do you think i might need writing everything manually from zero? I checked the properties i'm allowed to change but i want to create an array of checkboxes and then add an actionlistener through a loop now for each of them individually

Answer (score 0):

How about if you extend the generated class? So the generated class is untouched but your subclass will have you manual changes. You will have to change the code that uses the class to use the subclass instead of the generated class though.

Will that suffice your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your variables under that section (a line or two under it).
you will not be able to edit the area that contains variables generated by netbeans but you can add as many variables as you want. then you can reference them anywhere in your code.
Netbeans will not touch your manually declared variables.